# convert UTC date to local time in javascript (moment.js)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, momentjs

I receive the following date as JSON data from an ASP.NET webapi2 service.

```
{
    creationDate: "2014-11-18T15:16:56.363"
    ... //other fields...
}
```

The dates in the system are stored as UTC dates, independent of the time zone.
When the data is returned and displayed on screen the incorrect time is used, as moment assumes that the date being parsed is local time, not UTC.

```
moment(text).tz('Africa/Johannesburg').fromNow();
```

Gives me time values two hours in the past, when they should actually be current. How do I parse / pass the date so that moment knows it should add the time zone. In my case GMT+2 or SAST.

Adding the time zone (GMT) doesn't seem to help.

```
Date.parse('2017-04-15T09:09:48.9590011 UTC')
```

results in `NaN`

Comment: From the [official documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/): _"If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use moment.utc() instead of moment()."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. Add a `Z` to the end of the string:

   ```
   moment(creationDate + "Z")
   ```
2. Use `.utc` and then `.local`:

   ```
   moment.utc(creationDate).local()
   ```

Here's an example, using a date that's almost always in daylight savings time ("summer time") so that it even works for those of us in the UK (who are otherwise on GMT, so it can be hard to tell whether we're getting UTC or local results :-) ):

```js
var creationDate = "2014-05-18T15:16:56.363";
console.log("String:", creationDate);
console.log("1:", moment(creationDate + "Z").toString());
console.log("2:", moment.utc(creationDate).local().toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you send/receive the date both client and server will try to convert to their time zone, the trick is that, pass the date as string.
When you returning or sending the data remove the **"T"**

```
{
    creationDate: "2014-11-18 15:16:56.363"
    ... //other fields...
}
```

OR

```
data.creationDate.replace('T', ' ')
```

So when client receive the data it will not change or convert the date. then you can use

```
new Date(moment(data.creationDate.replace('T', ' ')))
```

This will return what you have sent from server